# Are there precautions that one should take when a Cassandra Docker container changes IP?

Tags: docker, cassandra

I often observe that container IPs change during run time, hence I was wondering if these occurrences have any consequences especially when it comes to Cassandra containers in a cluster.

Are there any precautions to consider or does Docker resolve everything?

For example, is it possible for a container cluster node to be seen as a dead node due to a container IP change? **Without Docker** we can tackle dead node replacement with the -Dcassandra.replace_address option to specify that *old_ip* is now *new_ip*, do I need to do the same **with Docker**?

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 2):

If you are running Cassandra in a container then with the sufficient port mappings you should be fine for that one container. However, other Cassandra nodes should be made aware of the IP change of the container.

The `CASSANDRA_BROADCAST_ADDRESS` is meant for this. It specifies which IP address to advertise to other nodes. You can supply this as an environment variable when you are starting your container.